# CSS not applying to XHTML

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS/XHTML. I have a stylesheet defined externally, and am trying to use it in my HTML file.

The contents of the .css file are simply:

```
borderstyle {
     font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 20%;
     font-style:normal;
     border: blue dotted medium;
     display: inline;
}
```

Here is where I am attempting to use it in my HTML:

```
 <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css" />
        <center>
            <div class ="borderStyle">
                Welcome
            </div>
        </center>
 </body>
```

The Welcome text is appearing centered, but with normal formatting, and no border.

Update: This is an XHTML file, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The `<center>` tag was deprecated in HTML4 and **removed** in HTML5. I suggest you remove it too :)

Answer (score 4):

`borderstyle` is a class, not an element, the selector should be prepended by a period, use:

```
.borderstyle {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Further, I'd suggest wrapping the Times New Roman font-name with quotes (`'Times New Roman'`), and `center` is deprecated, use CSS `auto` for the left, and right, margins, or `text-align: center;` on the parent element, as you've assigned `display: inline`.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are all valid. You should correct all the errors they mention.

But there is one additional error that hasn't been mentioned: the class name, `"borderStyle"`. If you target that with CSS, you should use the same casing. I.E. `.borderStyle` rather than `.borderstyle`.

Summary of the other errors, for completeness:

- `borderstyle` in the css needs a period
- The `<link>` element should be in the head
- `<center>` shouldn't be used

In addition, I'd say 20% for a font size is awfully small. On most browsers, this amounts to about 3px. Did you mean 200%?

Comment: The use of `center` is, however, irrelevant to the problem posed. In practice, `link` works in `body`, too. So the two things that cause the problem are the lack of `.` in the selector and the wrong case of one letter there. Regarding the code as a whole, it should be dumped and written from scratch, starting from something like `<div class=greeting>Welcome</div>` (if you want a childish-looking “Welcome” text).

Comment: You're right about the class name not being a very good one. But I'm not sure about the link element. Putting it in the wrong place is definitely an error that should be mentioned! Besides, if it's really XHTML, will all browsers still respond the same? I don't think it's worth the risk. Better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `.` in the selector of your CSS rule and the class name should be spelled `borderStyle` rather than `borderstyle` in order to match the class name in the HTML. Try this instead:

```
.borderStyle {
     font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 20%;
     font-style:normal;
     border: blue dotted medium;
     display: inline;
}
```

Also, you should move the link to your CSS file into the `<head>` section of the webpage, e.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css" />
    </head>
    <body>    
        <!-- body content omitted for brevity -->    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still nothing. For some reason, it is still not applying.

Comment: @user1154644 I just spotted another error - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

add . befor class and center the text through css, and add style link in head area

```
.borderstyle {
    font-family:"Times New Roman, Times, serif";
    font-size: 20%;
    font-style:normal;
    border: blue dotted medium;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and this the html without center tag and still the text centered

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css" />
<head>
<body>
<div class ="borderStyle">
    Welcome
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Link to CSS file should be put in the head section, not in the body.

Ex:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css" />
</head>
<body>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For classes

```
.borderstyle
```

for ids

```
#borderstyle
```

tags

```
div
```

type, name or any other attribute

```
[type="type"]
```